# Hosting platform strips out handlebars.js curly brackets, how else can I add in the template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js

I'm attempting to create a slider where each slide is created using a handlebars.js template, it works locally but when I upload it to our custom hosting platform it strips out the curly brackets, which as you might expect breaks it.

Is there any way I can pull the template in from somewhere else so I don't have to include it in the page?

```
<script id="carousel-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="topProducts__slider">
    {{#each products}}

        <div class="topProducts__slide">
            <a href="{{link}}" class="ga-ip" data-ip-position="top products slider" data-ip-name="{{title}}">
                <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/jpl/jd_{{plu}}_a?qlt=80&w=250&h=250&v=2" /> 
                <h4>{{title}}</h4>
                <p class="slideDesc">{{desc}}</p>
                <p class="slidePrice">&pound;{{price}}</p>
            </a>


        </div>

        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Update: Unknown exactly why the custom CMS strips them out, although apparently they use twig templating so that might have something to do with it. Contacting support may take days so looking for any potential ideas. Anything where the template isn't in the HTML document when it loads might work. Ajax call?

Comment: Without knowing anything about this "custom" hosting platform, it's impossible to know why it doesn't work, or what would work instead.

Comment: Can't go in to detail about why it doesn't work because to be honest I don't know why it's set up to strip them out, in a situation where I have to use it but can't control it. As for what would work instead I'm willing to try any suggestions, just throw them out there. Anything where it's not in the page as HTML when it loads is likely to work. AJAX call?

Comment: Maybe ask the tech support of the hosting service?

Comment: A good suggestion but a slow process, I'm talking days.